# From where can I take the green camera icon from hangouts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api, google-hangouts

I did manage to take the gray (disabled) hangouts icon from the app using this:

```
"<span class='rtc-hangout-icon-disabled goog-inline-block'></span>"
```

By inspecting google.calendar.com and I've seen that it uses this:

```
 hangout-icon-disabled {
background-image: url(//calendar.google.com/googlecalendar/images/combined_v46_vr.png);
height: 10px;
margin-right: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 16px;
```

}
as it's styles. Now I am trying to get the green image. and I tried using a class like rtc-hangout-icon-enabled. but there is no such thing. and I tried but I can't make that icon appear in calendar.google.com. So I'm kind of stuck at this. Is there any other way to find that picture?
PS: Tried to take it from Hangouts, but there the class id is just something like:

```
"<span class='ZQwIvc'></span>"
```

Comment: What does this have to do with extensions? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: It's an chrome extension. Which uses google calendar. So when u will create an event, it will add some views, if the extension is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a sprite, I just played with the class, and background position until I found the correct values, in order to show my needed picture.
using the background image and this line I made it work:

```
"<span class='rtc-hangout-icon-disabled goog-inline-block' style='background-position:-278px -64px;'></span>";
```